# AngularJS dynamically inject scope or controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to inject scope or controller during running ? 
or any other advice to dynamically inject services into controller ?

```
Application.controller('IndexController', function($scope){

    // some actions

    if(someconditions) {
            $scope.$inject = [someServiceName];
            // and here i want to use service methods 
    }

});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is i don't know what kind of service i'll receive after actions happened before. thats why i'm confused, any advice in this case ?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

A service can be dynamically injected (by name) into a controller using the [$injector](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24injector).  Being able to inject services via controller arguments is just a convenience that Angular provides.  Under the hood, the $injector is used by Angular to retrieve object instances.  But we can use the $injector ourselves also.

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $injector) {
  $scope.doSomething = function(someService) {
    var service = $injector.get(someService)  // someService contains the name of a service
    service.value += 10
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/vaANv/).

Comment: Huh. OK. I stand corrected. But what is the benefit of this (besides not having a mile long arguments list)?

Comment: @Joe, I've never used the $injector directly myself.  I suppose Mass might be the person to ask for a good use case. :)

Comment: I would caution against over use of the $injector. Having a visible list of dependencies tells me how much work is my controller doing and might force me to split the work

Comment: Thanks for answer, @JoeDyndale & I am going to use this inside generic directive, who has it's own controller, and need to feed with services dynamically as parameter.

Comment: Use case for me is for wrapping REST API. Each 'model' type can return related items of other types, so you need to be able to dynamically select the correct service to represent the REST API relatives.

Comment: One huge advantage of this approach is when you have a common public interface between a set of services, where you only need to execute 1 service depending on a condition. Instead of having 100 dependencies just in case you have to execute one of those services, you can inject it by name on the fly

Comment: @JoeDyndale I'm using this to conditionally inject a service inside my controller only if required

Comment: @MarkRajcok: You fiddle has expired

Comment: @Shashank, it came up just now when I tried it.  If that link doesn't work for you, try http://jsfiddle.net/vaANv/98/

Answer (score 4):

Following is one use case i came across recently,
I was trying to inject the a service "myService" in the Factoy and got the following error.

```
**Uncaught Error:** *[$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <- $modal <- myService <- interceptorFactory <- $http <- $templateRequest <- $compile*

[http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/cdep?p0=%24http%20%3C-%20%24mod%E2%80%A6orFactory%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24compile][1]
```

To solve this issue, $injector came as life saver

```
var service = $injector.get('myService') //this will create a dynamic service instance
```

and now you can use the service in a similar way you have used other services in your application.

Comment: I cannot emphasize enough how good this answer is.  The rest of our team and I spent almost a week coming up with various solutions to work around the circular imports/dependencies issue (for a case where it isn't even a logical restriction: factories that return stateless helper functions).  Importing `$injector` and calling e.g. `var someImportMakingAngularDizzy = $injector.get('someImportMakingAngularDizzy')` solved all of that in about 15 minutes.  Thank you!

Comment: I am glad, it helped you and your team.