# Directive to iterate over service result without controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm investigating the possibility of using AngularJS as a framework for defining web components declaratively (avoiding the need for controllers as much as possible). The majority of the functionality required can already be achieved with Angular's inbuilt directives, however I would also like to be able to iterate over the results of various services used to request data asynchronously.

The functionality I need could be easily achieved by injecting the service into a controller and storing the result on the scope, but I was hoping there would be a method for achieving this without needing a controller at all (specifically, I'm hoping to generate templates rather than hand write them).

Is there any built in way to achieve this in Angular (e.g. a way to include a service call to a repeat expression)? If not, what would be the most effective way of accomplishing this? I would assume that I should be able to create a new directive that takes a reference to a service, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to achieve this.

Comment: You can inject services into directives just like you can with controllers.  Is this sufficient for your needs?

Comment: Would it be possible to create a general purpose 'ng-repeat-service' directive with this technique, or would I need to create a new directive for each service I wanted to use? Sorry if this seems like an obvious question, I haven't actually used Angular properly yet, so far I'm still trying to decide if it's appropriate for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a general purpose directive, where a service can be declared in the HTML rather than be injected as part of the directive definition, the $injector can be used:

```
<some_element ... my-directive service="myService">
```

Directive:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function($injector) {
    return {
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var service = $injector.get(attrs.service);
          service.someMethod();
          ...
       }
    }
});
```

Note: I haven't yet tested the above technique to see if will actually work, but I've [tried the technique with controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14418384/215945) and it works.

For this technique to be useful, you'd obviously have to come up with a static service API, and only services that use that API could be used.

Comment: +1 You could also get "fancy" with a nested directives, having the outside directive pull in the service and the inside directive use whatever service the outer directive provides.