# Good Practices of AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

After searching for hours in google and stackoverflow, I did not get the answer for good practices for AngularJS.

My Questions Are ::

1) Is it a good practice to manipulate a DOM **using JQuery and CSS** in AngularJS?

2) **When to** add $injector and $inject explicitly?

3) Is it good practice **to use JQuery's $.ajax() method** to call the asynchronously in the **controller of a Module**?

Comment: Point 1. Only manipulate inside a directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Is it a good practice to manipulate a DOM using JQuery and CSS in AngularJS?

You may be surprised how much Angular can do without jQuery.  However, [jqLite](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element) is certainly a "lite" version of jQuery.  If you can't do it "clean" in Angular (e.g., if you find yourself writing `parent().parent()` instead of `closest('.element-wrapper')`) then sure, reach for jQuery.

> 2) When to add $injector and $inject explicitly?

Normal [dependency injection](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) is usually sufficient.  You could, however, dynamically inject a service using the $injector, if you really need to: [AngularJS dynamically inject scope or controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415845/angularjs-dynamically-inject-scope-or-controller)

> 3) Is it good practice to use JQuery's $.ajax() method to call the asynchronously in the controller of a Module?

Use [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http) or [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource).  They do things $.ajax() doesn't, e.g., they'll initiate an AngularJS digest cycle when results come back from the server.  Often, you'll want to put your server interaction code into an Angular [service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.understanding_services).

Comment: Thanks a lot **Mark**! And would you please point me towards good documentation of AngularJS. The documentation at their site is poorly constructed.I want to go through the topics in depth.(I am a newbie to AngularJS)

Comment: @Srinivas, well, right now, I really can't point you anywhere else for documentation.  I learned (I'm still learning) AngularJS from the docs, watching videos, and by reading SO and trying to answer people's questions (which caused me to do a lot of Internet searching and fiddling).