# How to dynamically choose a repository/service to be used in a directive/controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I have a directive that gets data from the database but I want it to use different repositories (with the same API) in different places in the project. The incoming data has similar fields so that is not a problem. Is there a way to pass that as a parameter through the directive tag like

```
<div my-directive="my-directive" service="Services.MovieService"></div>
<div my-directive="my-directive" service="Services.ActorService"></div>
```

or what would be the best practice so I don't have if/else nightmares and dependency injection bloat using a string that would represent the service name?

How would that be done for plain controllers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service can be dynamically injected  into a controller of directive using the $injector by its name. Being able to inject services via controller arguments is just a convenience that Angular provides. Under the hood, the $injector is used by Angular to retrieve object instances. But we can use the $injector ourselves also.

for instance, it is you controller function of your directive

```
  controller :($scope, $injector) {
  if(your_condition)
 { var ser= $injector.get(someService)  // someService contains the name of a service
  }
```

here your condtion can be any condition in order to check whether to include a service or not

Comment: This is interesting although I believe this is going to make a huge list of if-else's which I want to avoid. What I could do is pass the condition to the $injector and it will get me the right service. But I guess even with that there is no way to avoid the if-else's right?

Comment: yes you can, at the end you have to pass a service name in get() . yes but i think having too many conditions for injecting a servie will be against the declarative approach of angular, you wont be expecting that much . it wcan be couple of consitions only

Comment: So what do you suggest if let's say I have ten services?

Comment: finding this exact answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14418384/986160) to a different question, I realized that I don't need any if/elses and I can pass the name of the service directly to the $injector. Accepted! Thanks