# How to dynamically inject modules and services into app and controllers in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I have an app that decides if it needs a specific set of modules inside of the application run block. (Removed all unnecessary logic)

```
angular.module('myApp', []).run(function () {
    if (true) {
        //needs to have modules injected into myApp
    }
});
```

How can I add modules to myApp, after my angular app has initiated?

Once the module is injected dynamically, how can I use the injected module's services in other places of my app, like controllers and directives?

```
angular.module('myApp').controller(function ($scope, myService) {  //where myService belongs to a dynamically added module

    myService.doStuff(); //this would give me an error if the module wasn't injected
});
```

I know it's possible to just add all modules with Inline Array Annotation, then just checking if myService exists, inside of my controllers. But I'm trying to do this the correct way, instead of having to check for myService, thought-out my whole code base.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415845/angularjs-dynamically-inject-scope-or-controller

Comment: Thank you for the link Mathos. Seems like services can be dynamically injected without much work. I wonder if there's a similar solution for injecting modules!

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly bootstrap your application module after determining what you need.

```
var modulesToInject = ["myDep1"];
// push more modules here as needed
angular.module("myApp", modulesToInject);
angular.bootstrap(document,["myApp"]);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, Uncharted. I'm looking for a way to do add the module after the app has started running, ideally inside of the application's run block.

Comment: You could wrap what I put in some kinda of "config" module and do in that one's run. Could you expand on what your end goal is or why your trying to do it this way?