# Bind custom javascript event to angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, iscroll4

I'm working on a mobile application where I have list with some items. This list can be pulled down to inititate a refresh of the list (I'm using iScroll4). I'm now trying to hook this event up to my angular controller so I can make an api call and update the model.

The javascript is basically as follows:

```
[..] //javascript code to detect the pulldown event

function pullDownAction(){
     //I want to update the scope here
}
```

Based on what I have read, I need to make an angular directive and call the event from there, but I still haven't figured out where the above piece of code should go.

I have also tried broadcasting the event from within the pullDownAction function and listening to it in the controller, like so:

```
function pullDownAction(){
    var $rootScope = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$rootScope');
    $rootScope.$apply(function(){
          $rootScope.$broadcast('updateInbox');
    });
});
```

and then in the controller:

```
$scope.$on('updateInbox', function(){
     $http.get(apiUrl)
         .success(function (data) {
              $scope.model = data;
        });           
});
```

But I'm sure I'm missing something important which makes the code not work. I'm quite new to angular, so I haven't really gotten the hang of how directives work yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work by putting all the javascript code for the event in the link function:

```
app.directive('pullToRefresh', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'AC',
    link:
    function (scope, element, attr) {
            //Code to detect when element is pulled goes here

            function pullDownAction(){
                 scope.$eval(attr.pulldown);
            }
```

I then just put an attribute in the container called pulldown, and they now have access to the same scope. My element looks like this:

```
<div class="pull-to-refresh" pulldown="update()">
   //Element to be "pull-to-refreshable" here
</div>
```

update() is of course a function in the controller where you can do whatever you want!

Answer (score 2):

In the link function of your directive, setup the iScroll4 plugin.  Define `pullDownAction()` inside your link function also.  Then, due to the closure, you will have access to the scope.

```
app.directive('iscroll4Wrapper', function() {
    return {
       link: function(element, scope, attrs) {
          var pullDownAction = function() {
            // update scope here
          }
          $(??).iScroll4({   // I have no idea how to initialize this
            onSomeEvent: function(...) {
               pullDownAction();
               scope.$apply();  // or put this in pullDownAction()
            }
          });
       }
    }
}
```

What you tried with the injector didn't work because [you created new injector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14743553/215945).

Comment: I made it work almost the way you described, see my answer! Thanks :)