# Explain please AngularJS $injector with a clear example

Tags: angularjs

Due to deficiency of official docs explanation on `$injector` (service) I have hard time understanding how it actually works. How many `$injector`s may be per application? When should I use it? How does `$injector` work? (and so on) Please provide me with a real world explanation and some JavaScript sandbox samples on it.

Comment: You need to be more specific.

Comment: this site is not about demanding code delivered to you, rather about you providing code you have problems with and need help with

Comment: FWIW, I found the answer that this question elicited very helpful. As someone new to angular, I am happy that it was asked and answered. To me, it seems like a real question.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There is one injector per Angular application.  Normally you don't need to interact with it directly.  The injector is key to making dependency injection work in Angular.

Module methods such as `factory`, `service`, `directive`, etc. register these items with the injector.  When you inject something (e.g., a service into a controller), the injector will lookup and then instantiate the service (if it wasn't instantiated already -- if it was, it will return the already-instantiated object).

If for some reason you really needed to dynamically inject a service into, say, a controller, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14418384/215945 for an example of how to do that.
See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/14743553/215945.

Comment: better explaination than doc .