# Declare angular modules dependency on basis of some data from server

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

I have created two different modules  in **app.js** like:

**app.js**

```
angular.module('userModule', []);
angular.module('adminModule', []);  
angular.module('mainApp', ["userModule","adminModule"]);
```

I want to do like:

```
if(loggedInUserAdmin)
{
  angular.module('mainApp', ["userModule","adminModule"]);
}
else
{
  angular.module('mainApp', ["userModule"]);
}
```

And loggedInUserAdmin is a flag that I need to have from server after index.html loads,I would like to know how can I structure my app.js's code so I can wait till a ajax call completed and then I can decide which modules to be injected?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found this. I think it could be what you are looking for..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758157/angularjs-how-to-inject-dynamically-dependence-in-a-controller

Comment: Hi Ashraf, above link saying about how to inject depedency in a controller,but I want to do it at module level.

Comment: can't you have server write which version to use? Alternatively, can manually bootstrap angular after the ajax call. Give each of your module versions a different name and bootstrap the one that is appropriate