# Dynamically inject dependency module in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I have a web application into which another widget should be integrated. The widget script is loaded asynchronously and takes around 10 sec to load.I want to add this widget module as a dependency in my angular application after the relevant scripts are loaded. Is this actually feasible? I am using ng-app to bootstrap my application.In another comment, I found that dynamic injection of modules is possible only before bootstraping the application.Is there any workaround for this or is this bad approach altogether?

**Edit:** The application should not be dependent on the loading of widget since it is only an integration.As many people have suggested, when i use requireJS,it forces the bootstrap of application to wait till the widget loads. Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: Have you checked out require.js?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758157/how-to-inject-dynamically-dependence-in-a-controller have you seen this?

Comment: The question you mentioned deals with injecting a service into my controller. I want to add a new dependency module into my angular application.

Comment: @SatejS require.js is an option but one should have better understanding of both Angular and Require before using them together, Here is another option for lazy loading http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 0):

If you can bear `requirejs` with `angularjs` then `angularAMD` is the option:

[AngularJS + RequireJS: The Proper and Easier Way](http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/#/home)

If you choose to go with direct option:

[Lazy Loading In AngularJS](http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/)

Comment: As mentioned in the comment to the question, this deals with lazy loading of controllers,services etc in a module. I need to load a dependency module.Is it totally different or am i missing something?

Comment: Its samething you just need to put some time on the links provided, so that you have better understanding of task and its accomplishment. Its same what you need.

Comment: The above approaches make the application dependent on widget module (bootstraping after the module loads). However, the application should not be dependent on the widget. Ideally, even if the widget fails to load, the app should be up and running